# D3.js v4 elements are going back to initial position after dragging

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an SVG having some groups and drag behavior. It works nice but when I drag elements twice they start again from "initial" position. I need fresh eyes to fix this!

**Example**: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uncoke/eh0kfynp/11/)

And a snippet:

```js
var items = [{name:"A", x:50, y:50}, {name:"B", x:150, y:50}];
var size = 96;

var svg = d3.select("#container")
              .append("svg");
              
 var items = svg.selectAll("g")
         .data(items)
                .enter()
                  .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", function(d, i){
                      return "translate(" + (10+i*size+10*i) + "," + 10 + ")";
                    });
                  
                    
     items.call(d3.drag()
      // .subject(function(d) { return d; })
       // .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", draggedGroup)
          .subject(function() { 
            var t = d3.select(this);
            return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
    })
        //.on("end", dragended)
      );
                    
                    
    items
       .append("rect")
         .attr("x",function(d){return d.x;})
         .attr("y",function(d){return d.y;})
         .attr("height",size)
         .attr("width", size)
         .style("stroke", "#0F0")
         .style("fill", "transparent")
         .style("stroke-width", 3.5);
         
    items.append("line")
       .style("stroke", "#0FF")
         .attr("x1", function(d){return d.x;})
         .attr("y1", function(d){return d.y;})
         .attr("x2", function(d){return d.x+size;})
         .attr("y2", function(d){return d.y+size;})
         
     items.append("line")
       .style("stroke", "#0FF")
         .attr("x1", function(d){return d.x+size;})
         .attr("y1", function(d){return d.y;})
         .attr("x2", function(d){return d.x;})
         .attr("y2", function(d){return d.y+size;})
         
    items .append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d){return d.x+size/2})
        .attr("y", function(d){return d.y+size/2})
              //.attr("text-anchor", "start")
         .style("fill", "white")
         .text(function(d){
            return d.name;
           })
      
         
function dragstarted(d){
 console.log("Moving "+d.name);
//  d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
} 

function draggedGroup(d, i, a){

  const pos   = [d3.event.x , d3.event.y];
  const pdist = [d3.event.dx , d3.event.dy];
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate("+pos[0]+","+pos[1]+")")
    
} 

function dragended(d){
 // d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", false);
  console.log("Stop moving "+d.name)
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
  padding:10px;
}

svg{
  
   width:500px;
  height:400px;
}

#container{
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: #00F;
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

My **Grouped** items:

```
var items = svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(items)
                .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", function(d, i){
                        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                    });


items.append("rect")
     .attr("x",function(d){return d.x;})
     .attr("y",function(d){return d.y;})
     .attr("height",size)
     .attr("width", size)
     .style("stroke", "#0F0")
     .style("fill", "transparent")
     .style("stroke-width", 3.5);

items.append("line")
            .style("stroke", "#0FF")
     .attr("x1", function(d){return d.x;})
     .attr("y1", function(d){return d.y;})
     .attr("x2", function(d){return d.x+size;})
     .attr("y2", function(d){return d.y+size;})

 items.append("line")
         .style("stroke", "#0FF")
     .attr("x1", function(d){return d.x+size;})
     .attr("y1", function(d){return d.y;})
     .attr("x2", function(d){return d.x;})
     .attr("y2", function(d){return d.y+size;})

items .append("text")
            .attr("x", function(d){return d.x+size/2})
            .attr("y", function(d){return d.y+size/2})
                            //.attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .text(function(d){
            return d.name;
       })
```

**Behaviors**

```
   items.call(d3.drag()
      .on("drag", draggedGroup)
      .subject(function() { 
         var t = d3.select(this);
        return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
       })
  );
```

**Drag function**

```
function draggedGroup(d, i, a){
    const pos   = [d3.event.x , d3.event.y];
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate("+pos[0]+","+pos[1]+")")  
 }
```

Why it restarts from first position when I try to drag element for the second time?  See the example on jsfiddle to see in action.

The error seems to be in this line of drag function:

```
 d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate("+(pos[0])+","+(pos[1])+")")
```

**EDIT**

I tried to update the **STOP** function to update the starting values to

```
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d){

             d.x += d3.event.x;
             d.y += d3.event.y;

        return "translate("+d3.event.x+","+d3.event.y+")"
})
```

Now if I put the d.x, d.y in console when the dragging starts the output shows

> x: 640
>   y: 299

but the box starts always in inital position. I'm confused

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The reason it always starts from the initial position is because the initial position never changes. The `x` and `y` never change. You simply transform the location with a translate, but everytime you start a drag that transformation starts from the initial `x` and `y`.

Comment: yes. this is correct. How fix it?

Comment: Why it works here . https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/204d08d309d2b2903e12554b0aef6a4d?

Comment: I have answered based on the code in the fiddle, which differs from the code in the question (initial transform on `g` elements). I've brought the code in from the fiddle to the question as it what I build off of for the answer. Though, I see you edited the question to remove this part of the code. If my answer solves your problem, I may edit it back for the sake of consistency. The subject and the initial transform are the two parts of the problem I address below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're positioning through both transforms and x/y attributes, this is causing some difficulty in seeing the issue perhaps. More importantly, the issue is a combination of positioning based on index and positioning based on datum.

### The Problem

If you remove the initial transform on the `g`:

```
"translate(" + (10+i*size+10*i) + "," + 10 + ")";
```

You get each set of elements/`g` without a transform:

[image]

Rectangle A is anchored at 50,50 and rectangle B at [150,150] (set with x,y attributes). The lines and text are also positioned similarly based off the anchor point. The translate in the image above is [0,0] for each `g`.

Now let's look at your drag subject:

```
     .subject(function() { 
        var t = d3.select(this);
        return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
     })
```

*I'll note that the `g`s (`this` above) don't have x or y attributes (the data does has x and y properties, but you are passing the HTML element's x and y attributes instead). Writing `return {x:null,y:null}` produces the same results*

D3 can handles this drag subject by treating the subject as [0,0]. All drags are therefore relative to [0,0], which means all drags for the `g` elements are relative to the image above, no matter where the last drag left the `g`: A drag of one pixel moves one of the boxes one pixel from the position in the image above, not from wherever position it may be at drag onset.

### Fixing the Problem

This is a bit trickier because of how you have positioned the data. You have set an initial translate that is independent of the bound data, but rather is dependent on the index. The bound data then is used to apply x,y attributes on top of this. Normally we would simply use the bound data to represent everything about the element's position.

Let's use the pattern in the [example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/204d08d309d2b2903e12554b0aef6a4d) you linked to in the comments first, and then adapt it.

This pattern uses the default subject of a drag:

```
function subject(d) {
  return d == null ? {x: d3.event.x, y: d3.event.y} : d;
}
```

If `d` is defined, which it is, we use the dragged element's bound datum as a reference point for the drag using the x and y properties. Then, during drag we update the datum to reflect its new position with something like:

```
function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)
    .attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y); 
}
```

This looks like:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height", 300);
  
var rect = svg.append("rect")
  .datum({x:50,y:50})
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)
        .attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y)
    })  
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

But, we run into problems using this with your code:

```js
var items = [{name:"A", x:50, y:50}, {name:"B", x:150, y:50}];
var size = 96;

var svg = d3.select("#container")
   .append("svg");
              
var items = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(items)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i){
     return "translate(" + (10+i*size+10*i) + "," + 10 + ")";
  });
                  
                    
items.call(d3.drag()
  .on("drag", draggedGroup)
  )
                    
items
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x",function(d){return d.x;})
   .attr("y",function(d){return d.y;})
   .attr("height",size)
   .attr("width", size)
   .style("stroke", "#0F0")
   .style("fill", "transparent")
   .style("stroke-width", 3.5);
         
items.append("line")
   .style("stroke", "#0FF")
   .attr("x1", function(d){return d.x;})
   .attr("y1", function(d){return d.y;})
   .attr("x2", function(d){return d.x+size;})
   .attr("y2", function(d){return d.y+size;})
         
items.append("line")
   .style("stroke", "#0FF")
   .attr("x1", function(d){return d.x+size;})
   .attr("y1", function(d){return d.y;})
   .attr("x2", function(d){return d.x;})
   .attr("y2", function(d){return d.y+size;})
         
items .append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d){return d.x+size/2})
   .attr("y", function(d){return d.y+size/2})
   .style("fill", "white")
   .text(function(d){
      return d.name;
   })

function draggedGroup(d, i, a){
    d.x = d3.event.x;
    d.y = d3.event.y;
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")")
    
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
  padding:10px;
}

svg{
  
   width:500px;
  height:400px;
}

#container{
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: #00F;
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Other than the initial jump on the first drag, everything works fine. The initial drag jumps, because the drag translate is relative to d.x and d.y, but the `g` elements are drawn with an initial translate that is not based on d.x or d.y, it is: `"translate(" + (10+i*size+10*i) + "," + 10 + ")"`.

This makes it difficult to adopt to the D3 pattern: the bound data isn't being used to position elements representing the data. Let's change that. Let's use the following data structure:

```
{
  name: same as before,
  x: drag position X,
  y: drag position Y,
  x1: anchor point X of rectangle, // currently d.x
  y1: anchor point Y of rectangle  // currently d.y
}
```

*Of course we need to update every reference of d.x/d.y*

Now we can use the x,y properties of the data to track the drag translate. We will set those to be the initial values used in the translate above. And we use x1 and y1 to set the anchor point for the rectangle (the x/y attributes of the rectangle):

```
 var items = [{name:"A", x1:50, y1:50}, {name:"B", x1:150, y1:50}];
 var size = 96;

 items.forEach(function(d,i) {
    d.x = 10+i*size+10*i;
    d.y = 10;
 })
```

Now we can set the initial translate with d.x/d.y, use the default drag subject, and update d.x and d.y on each drag event. Everything should be dandy:

```js
var items = [{name:"A", x1:50, y1:50}, {name:"B", x1:150, y1:50}];
var size = 96;

items.forEach(function(d,i) {
    d.x = 10+i*size+10*i;
    d.y = 10;
})

var svg = d3.select("#container")
   .append("svg");
              
var items = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(items)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i){
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
                    
                  
                    
items.call(d3.drag()
  .on("drag", draggedGroup)
  )
                    
items
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x",function(d){return d.x1;})
   .attr("y",function(d){return d.y1;})
   .attr("height",size)
   .attr("width", size)
   .style("stroke", "#0F0")
   .style("fill", "transparent")
   .style("stroke-width", 3.5);
         
items.append("line")
   .style("stroke", "#0FF")
   .attr("x1", function(d){return d.x1;})
   .attr("y1", function(d){return d.y1;})
   .attr("x2", function(d){return d.x1+size;})
   .attr("y2", function(d){return d.y1+size;})
         
items.append("line")
   .style("stroke", "#0FF")
   .attr("x1", function(d){return d.x1+size;})
   .attr("y1", function(d){return d.y1;})
   .attr("x2", function(d){return d.x1;})
   .attr("y2", function(d){return d.y1+size;})
         
items .append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d){return d.x1+size/2})
   .attr("y", function(d){return d.y1+size/2})
   .style("fill", "white")
   .text(function(d){
      return d.name;
   })

function draggedGroup(d, i, a){
    d.x = d3.event.x 
    d.y = d3.event.y
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")")
    
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
  padding:10px;
}

svg{
  
   width:500px;
  height:400px;
}

#container{
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: #00F;
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Andrew! Amazing answer! Thanks for fixing and super thanks for explaining the issue! I really appreciated! I love d3 but I don't use it very often so when I need it I go in trouble! I saw your great work with it! Really great!!! I'll use lichens.js! Absolutely! I know I shouldn't say thanks here in comments but... today I have to offer a beer to someone! :D Great job buddy!